# can i read content from my private folder?

Tags: android

i have made a program in which i make a file in the `data/data/mypackagename/` directory. From there i try and attach the file to an email and send it.

The problem that occurs is the file appears while sending the email as an attachment but the attachment is never received when the mail is received.

I believe that some problem is occuring when URI parse the file in the code:

```
emailintent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://"+outFileName));
```

My question is can i access data of the private folder in my phone, or should i always put it inside the sdcard.

If i put the file that i am making inside the sdcard, will the attachment problem dissappear?

Comment: is outFileName the full path of the file?

Comment: yes...outFileName is as follows /data/data/com.company.NauticDates/attachment.ics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is can i access data of the root folder in my phone, or should i always put it inside the sdcard.

Your application can access data in your application-local data store -- the directory returned by `getFilesDir()`.

However, you did not write the email program. The email program was written by somebody else, and you are starting an activity in that other application. The email program does not have rights to read files in *your* application's data store.

You will either need to keep the file in question on external storage, as others have suggested, or use the version of `openFileOutput()` that takes `MODE_WORLD_READABLE` as a parameter, so you have a file that other applications (such as the email program) can read.

> outFileName is as follows /data/data/com.company.NauticDates/attachment.ics

I certainly hope not. That should be `/data/data/com.company.NauticDates/files/attachment.ics`. Please do not hardwire paths in your application. Please use the appropriate methods to get directories for you to use, such as `getFilesDir()` or `openFileOutput()` to put files in the application-local file store.

Comment: what is wrong with hardwiring paths? Also could you give me an idea as to the use of getfilesdir and openfileoutput?

Comment: @user743883: "what is wrong with hardwiring paths?" -- that assumes the paths are the same on all devices, and they are not. "Also could you give me an idea as to the use of getfilesdir and openfileoutput?" -- you should have found http://goo.gl/YnQic and http://goo.gl/TkDqi and http://goo.gl/xziPw in ten seconds of searching the developer documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the file in assets folder. and you can read file using the following code

```
InputStream myInput =  context.getAssets().open("filename");
```

Thanks
Deepak

Comment: The poster is not trying to read the file from their own program, but to pass it to a different program via an Intent, so that is unlikely to directly work.